# Constraint layout is not aligning widget properly with layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf for list item

Tags: xml, user-interface, android-recyclerview, layout, android-constraintlayout

I am using layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf tag for aligning widget to the right of another in constraint layout, but it is overlapping the first widget.

Below is my Layout item XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivDocumentIcon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_21sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_28sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_png" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutDocumentDetailsView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ivDocumentActionButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivDocumentIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFileName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:fontFamily="@font/rkt_sans_regular"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/dash"
            android:textColor="@color/color_333333"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvModifiedTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/rkt_sans_regular"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/dash"
            android:textColor="@color/triggered_wo_item_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/task_cr_time_bg" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivDocumentActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_document_action_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried to allign these view with each other but it make my images out of the screen.